# Missing session_start event - so no session source / medium either - but no measurement protocol

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I searched to see if a similar problem has been addressed, but I couldn't find it.

We have deployed measurement for GA4 via GTM for a client website, events measure beautifully, custom metrics and dimensions are being sent and everything is ok - except that the session source/medium dimension stopped working and the vast majority of purchases and revenue are coming from unassigned channel and (not set) source / medium.

I noticed that I don't see the session_start event for this portion of traffic, but I don't know why - I don't think I have any non-standard tag settings.

I also see in debug view that session_start is sent after the page_view event, could this be it? And what to do about it?

I was wondering if it's also a setting - I have signals turned off, report identity is set to "Observed" and I'm sending a user_id to the GA4.

I have seen multiple forums and articles that mention that this happens to server-side tracking or incorrect setup of measurement protocol, but we don't use any of this.

I tried switching the identity, turning on Google Signals, looking at the debug view in GA4 and via GTM preview.

When I rolled back all of my tags, it worked, but I would really like to send all my custom paratemters and dimensions too with my events and conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending a `campaign_details` event at the beginning of a client session?

More details here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/reference/events#campaign_details

Google's documentation says:

> Use this event to send campaign details that will be applied to future events.

...and it accepts `source` and `medium` as attributes.

Comment: Is it possible to do this via GTM?

Comment: We're using it via Measurement Protocol, so I'm not certain, but try these steps:

1. In Google Tag Manager, click Tags > New.
2. Enter a name for the GA4 Event tag
3. Select Google Analytics: GA4 Event.
4. Under Configuration Tag, select your Google tag.
5. In Event Name, enter a name for the event (campaign_details).
6. Configure event parameters. If the required parameters are not available by default, you might need to use Tag Manager's Data Layer functionality.

That said, since you're using GTM, things should "just work", so maybe there is a configuration error in your setup.

Comment: So, you have the parameters such as campaign and medium stored in your datalayer? But how about google ads (gclid) parameters?

Comment: We're using Measurement Protocol, so we're not using GTM or Data Layer. We just check the URL search parameters, referrer value etc. for anything relevant, and then submit that data with the `campaign_details` event. You save that same data to the Data Layer for later use in any events sent.

The `campaign_details` event seems to have a hidden (or at least undocumented) parameter `aclid`, which you can use to hold the `gclid` click id value. At least we got our Google Ads conversions working with this parameter.